# apache 2.4.6, error with module apr hooks

Tags: apache, module, apr

I'm trying to compile apache 2.4.6. I've successfully compiled and installed the latest apr (1.4.x) and apr-util (1.5.x).

Here are my environment settings, compilation settings, and modifications to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH after each package:

```
ENVPREFIX=/auto/custom-libs/linux/centos/6.x/x86_64/pkgs/httpd-2.4.6/
INSTALLPREFIX=${ENVPREFIX}
export PATH=${INSTALLPREFIX}/bin:$PATH

# APR compilation settings
./configure --prefix=${INSTALLPREFIX} --enable-other-child --enable-allocator-uses-mmap --enable-threads 
make -j16
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${INSTALLPREFIX}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# APR-util compilation settings
./configure --prefix=${INSTALLPREFIX} --with-apr=${ENVPREFIX}/bin/apr-1-config --with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql --with-crypto --with-ldap-lib=${ENVPREFIX}/lib --with-ldap-include=${ENVPREFIX}/include --with-openssl=/usr/lib64/openssl
make -j16
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${INSTALLPREFIX}/lib/apr-util-1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Apache httpd compilation parameters
./configure --prefix=${INSTALLPREFIX}  --enable-mpms-shared='all' --enable-rewrite --enable-ssl --enable-proxy --enable-cache --enable-pie  --enable-mods-shared='all' --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps  --enable-session --enable-proxy-balancer  --enable-usertrack --with-apr=${ENVPREFIX}/bin --with-apr-util=${ENVPREFIX}/bin 
make -j16
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${INSTALLPREFIX}/lib/modules/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

All is well until I start a vanilla site. All I change is the port to a non-standard 8000, and the username. Unfortunately, I encounter the following error which hints at some version incompatibility with the modules shipped with the latest apache 2.4.6 code.

Command:

```
httpd -f `pwd`/httpd.conf
```

Error output:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 137 of /home/prigor/codebase/pediatrics/webservices/pedws/pedws/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_session_cookie.so into server: /auto/igb-libs/linux/centos/6.x/x86_64/pkgs/httpd-2.4.6/modules/mod_session_cookie.so: undefined symbol: ap_hook_session_save
```

Even after disabling this module, the same error persists with the remaining modules. Perhaps I'm using the incorrect version for apr and apr-util? Perhaps I've set an incorrect config switch somewhere?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, some modules shipped with 2.4.6 aren't compatible with the apr/apr-utils. Just needed to comment out modules that caused error.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a very similar problem some minutes ago. But after some testing I realized that the real problem was this line (from `httpd.conf`):

```
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
```

It comes commented right after building/installation. After uncommenting that line (keeping `mod_session_cookie` and others also uncommented), everything worked fine.

I'm also using `HTTPD 2.4.6` and `APR 1.4.8`.

Comment: Also note that session_cookie_module must be loaded after session_module.  Trying to load session_cookie_mobule before session_module will produce the same undefined symbol error.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment this line (from `httpd.conf`):

```
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
```